# Rails where LIKE and array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I do something like this?

```
myarray = ["name1","name2"]
Product.where('name ILIKE ?', %#{myarray}%)
```

I need to get all products where names are like `name1` and `name2`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 59):

I think You want to test all values with  `ILIKE` function.

This is how it's done in Postgres:

```
select * from table where value ilike any (array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']);
```

Try to convert to Rails/Ruby syntax like this:

```
myarray_with_percetage_signs = ["name1","name2"].map {|val| "%#{val}%" }
Product.where("name ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", myarray_with_percetage_signs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently encountered the same issue, and, since neither answer helped me (I'm using a MySQL database), I thought I would share my solutions.

- If you have a small database and don't mind retrieving **all** products, you could do the filtering after retrieving all products from the database using the following:

  ```rb
  Product.select { |product| myarray.any? { |str| product.name.include? str } }
  ```
- If, however, you prefer to perform the query at the database level, you could use the `WHERE REGEXP` clause by converting the array to a pipe-separated list first:

  ```rb
  Product.where("`name` REGEXP '#{Regexp.new(myarray.join('|'))}'")
  ```

Comment: Careful with the recommendation in the second bullet:  the SQL is unsanitized. This can result in SQL injection. In particular, you want to avoid `where("id = #{some_var}")` and use this syntax instead: `where("id = ?", some_var)`. This allows ActiveRecord to sanitize the string, potentially via Prepared Statements.

Comment: Good catch, @Pete. I've updated my post to sanitize input. In my case, I didn't worry about SQL injections, because I wasn't working with user data, but with a constant pre-determined list, but this is definitely important if working with user-input data.

Answer (score -9):

```
Product.where('name IN (?)', myarray)
```

should do the trick ;)

Comment: While this will perform an exact match, it does not answer the question.  There does not match with SQL `LIKE`/`ILIKE` operator.