# Rails: Find all records where string column contains all words from an array of strings

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to filter all the records from a table where a column 'name' is like (in any order) all the values from an array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using postgres DB please check the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414415/8754174) since postgress has arrays.

You might want to do it at application level if your db is small.

If REGEXP is viable to you then the @khiav reoy answer is the best you could do.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

```
Model.where('name REGEXP ?', array_of_string.join('|'))
```